# Why isn't this method returning anything?

Tags: c#

This is for my internship so I can't give much more context, but this method isn't returning the desired int and causing an Index Out of Bounds exception instead.

The String[] taken into the method is composed of information from a handheld scanner used by my company's shipping department. Its resulting dataAsByteArray is really a Byte[][] so the .Length in the nested If statement will get the number of Bytes of a Bundle entry and then add it to fullBundlePacketSize as long as the resulting sum is less than 1000.

Why less than 1000? The bug I've been tasked with fixing is that some scanners (with older versions of Bluetooth) will only transmit about 1000 bytes of data to the receiver at a time. This method is to find how many bytes can be transmitted without cutting into a bundle entry (originally I had it hard coded to just transmit 1000 bytes at a time and that caused the receiver to get invalid bundle data).

The scanners are running a really old version of Windows CE and trying to debug in VS (2008) just opens an emulator for the device which doesn't help.

I'm sure it's something really simple, but I feel like a new set of eyes looking at it would help, so any help or solutions are greatly appreciated!

```
        private int MaxPacketSizeForFullBundle(string[] data)
        {
            int fullBundlePacketSize = 0;
            var dataAsByteArray = data.Select(s => Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(s)).ToArray();
            for (int i = 0; i < dataAsByteArray.Length; i++)
            {
                if ((fullBundlePacketSize + dataAsByteArray[i + 1].Length < 1000))
                {
                    fullBundlePacketSize += dataAsByteArray[i].Length;
                }
            }
            return fullBundlePacketSize;
        }
```

Comment: You debugged this? Add a break point and see what is going on :)

Comment: If it's not returning anything it will be throwing an Exception somewhere.  As @TGarrett says, you should debug it to see what is happening. My guess is that it's an index out of range exception when you do `dataAsByteArray[i+1]`

Comment: It cant not return *anything*, do you mean it returns `0` or perhaps throws an exception?

Comment: _What are the errors?_

Comment: It's for an application running on a Windows CE handheld device from ages ago, so debugging within VS doesn't really help because the emulator isn't working properly. I have to build it each time and test it on the device. The index out of range exception is definitely the issue! Thanks for all the quick responses!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take a look at your loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < dataAsByteArray.Length; i++)
{
    if ((fullBundlePacketSize + dataAsByteArray[i + 1].Length < 1000))
                                                ^^^^^
```

I suspect you are throwing an exception because you are indexing an array beyond its length.

Do you mean this?

```
for (int i = 0; i < (dataAsByteArray.Length - 1); i++)
```

Comment: I was also thinking... wouldn't the `Length` of the individual `dataAsByteArray` elements just be 1? If so, the `for` loop could be simplified to: `fullBundlePacketSize = dataAsByteArray.Length`

Comment: That did the trick! Thank you so much for the quick answer! And @BobKaufman, dataAsByteArray isn't named well is really a Byte Array of Byte Arrays.

Comment: @trcoats: Glad to help! It's so common it has a wikipedia article: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Off-by-one_error

Answer (score 0):

In conjunction is @n8wrl's answer. Your problem was accessing out of range exception. I believe you were attempting to access the actual byte values inside of the values in dataAsByteArray.

```
string[] data = {"444", "abc445x"};
int x = MaxPacketSizeForFullBundle(data);
```

dataAsByteArray = {byte[2][]}

byte[2][0] contains {byte[3]} which contains the actual values of each character in the string, so for "444", it would contain 52, 52, 52. You are probably attempting to access these individual values which means that you need to access the deeper nested bytes with byte[i][j] where `0<j<data[i].Length.`

Comment: Well, I didn't see the answer got accepted as I was writing this answer, but  from running a test version in my own test class, this is what I could conclude.